# Prometheus QL join two queries into one

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to do query with promQL joining two queries at the same time but Im failing, Im new to promQL so I am learning how to do it, so there is a recording rules that I dont have access to the remote cluster so I need to join the recording rule with another query

the promehteus recording rules is:

```
sum by(airline, message_type, sap, remote_type) (irate(accuracy_A{stat="segTvlOk"}[2m]))
```

So what im trying to de is replace the metric "accuracy_B" for the rule below (I have access to accuracy_A from the query above so somehow I need to join these two queries)

```
sum (accuracy_B{airline=~"$airline", message_type=~"$message_type", remote_type=~"$remote_type"})
```

I tried this:

```
sum (accuracy_B{airline=~".+", message_type=~".+", remote_type=~".+"}) 
 and on (airlone, message_type, sap, remote_type) 
  sum by(airline, message_type, sap, remote_type) (irate(accuracy_A{stat="segTvlOk", tenant_id="rbox"}[2m]))
```

but it does not work and I have been looking online but cant find any answer on how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you'll provide example of current queries output and expected output of your "join"